# What happens if you apply the "logarithm of a product" property to a negative number?

Tags: logarithms

We know that $\log_a xy=\log_a x + \log_a y$ and that logarithms of negative numbers are undefined. But what happens if we try to apply this property to let's say $-5$?

$\log_a-1*5=\log_a-1+\log_a5$

After that we can infinitely apply the same property, but where do we actually get the undefined part?

Comment: The log of a negative number is defined, albeit, non-uniquely.  For $x<0$, we have $\log x=\log|x|+i(2n+1)\pi$ for integer values of $n$.

Comment: You have written $\log_a(-1\cdot 5) = \log_a(-1) + \log_a(5)$. Note that the term $\log_a(-1)$ on the right hand side is not defined.

Comment: Maybe I am thinking this programmatically but similarly the $log_a (-1)$ would give $log_a(-1) + log_a1=log_a(-1)$, therefore the computation wouldn't halt somewhere, giving a clear undefined result.

Comment: By that logic $1=1+0$, and thus the computation wouldn't halt. Therefore $1$ is undefined?

Comment: Such challenges leads to creating new number fields. Dr. MV provided with the insight - expanding the real numbers into complex numbers allow dealing with the challenge presented.